# How to increment all Integer by 1 in a Set<Integer> (Java)?

Tags: java

If I want to increment wrapped Integer in a Set by 1 (e.g.input {2,5,7,8}, output {3,6,8,9}), how can I do that?

Comment: (If you wanted to modify in place, you'd have to copy all the elements out to another collections (as in answers below, but to a `List` would perhaps be marginally better), `clear` the original set and then `addAll` the new collection back in.)

Comment: Why not write some code for that?

Comment: Could you add a few lines of code that you have tried so far? We really don't want to do your homework for you, but are always available for help when you get stuck somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(2, 3, 4, 5));
Set<Integer> newSet = new HashSet<>();
for (Integer i : set) {
    newSet.add(i + 1);
}
set = newSet;
System.out.println(set);
// [3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Yes, you will need a new `Set`, you cannot modify the elements of a `Set`.

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8, you can do it easily by using Streams:

```
set = set.stream().map(Math::incrementExact).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

If you cannot modify the reference to the set, e.g. because it's a parameter and the caller needs to see the new values, or because the set is a final field, then you need to copy the new values back after clearing the original set. In that case, building a list is slightly better.

```
List<Integer> newValues = set.stream().map(Math::incrementExact).collect(Collectors.toList());
set.clear();
set.addAll(newValues);
```